# Regular Expression Dictionary Search Single Use Letters

Tags: java, regex

I'm working on a Java program that searches through a dictionary for words made up of a particular set of letters. I am wondering if it's possible to set up a regular expression that would let you use a character only as often as it appears in a string. For example, with the letters SHARE. Hear, hares, sea, are etc. would be valid. But see or sarah would not be valid because you only have one e or one a respectively.

Comment: Please don't include "Thanks" in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: regular expressions are about patter matching. you want to take SHARE and make it only matches 0 o r 1 time for each letter.  SHARES would be 2 or 1 or 0 matches for S and 1 or 0 for the rest.  AND the kicker doesn't contain other letters.  This doesn't feel like pattern matching to me.

Comment: How are you storing the dictionary? Hashmap? Or are you planning to iterate on every word in the dictionary? Or is the dictionary just a very long string on which to run regex on?

Comment: I have the dictionary stored in a string array.

Comment: Is it too costly to search in the dictionary every permutation of the string (and substrings)?

Comment: I believe the major cost in that case lies in finding all those permutations.

Comment: it would likely be quicker to find all the permutations of the letters than it would be than to do a regex on 40k works or even the ~200k in the dictionary and their derivatives.  Once you have the permutations you could do a hash table lookup to see if they are words.

Comment: Yes, I think I will try to do this without regular expressions. As people have pointed out, it's probably not the best method. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are about pattern matching. Finding a simple pattern would probably not be possible.

If you **really really really** want a regex, these functions will generate one:

```
public  static String permutation(String str) {
    return "^" + permutation("",str).replaceFirst("\\|", "(") + ")$";
 }

 private static String permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    String s = "";
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) return "|"+prefix;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           s += permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i)+"?",
                            str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
    return s;
}
```

For "share" it will return:

```
^(s?h?a?r?e?|s?h?a?e?r?|s?h?r?a?e?|s?h?r?e?a?|s?h?e?a?r?|s?h?e?r?a?|s?a?h?r?e?|s?a?h?e?r?|s?a?r?h?e?|s?a?r?e?h?|s?a?e?h?r?|s?a?e?r?h?|s?r?h?a?e?|s?r?h?e?a?|s?r?a?h?e?|s?r?a?e?h?|s?r?e?h?a?|s?r?e?a?h?|s?e?h?a?r?|s?e?h?r?a?|s?e?a?h?r?|s?e?a?r?h?|s?e?r?h?a?|s?e?r?a?h?|h?s?a?r?e?|h?s?a?e?r?|h?s?r?a?e?|h?s?r?e?a?|h?s?e?a?r?|h?s?e?r?a?|h?a?s?r?e?|h?a?s?e?r?|h?a?r?s?e?|h?a?r?e?s?|h?a?e?s?r?|h?a?e?r?s?|h?r?s?a?e?|h?r?s?e?a?|h?r?a?s?e?|h?r?a?e?s?|h?r?e?s?a?|h?r?e?a?s?|h?e?s?a?r?|h?e?s?r?a?|h?e?a?s?r?|h?e?a?r?s?|h?e?r?s?a?|h?e?r?a?s?|a?s?h?r?e?|a?s?h?e?r?|a?s?r?h?e?|a?s?r?e?h?|a?s?e?h?r?|a?s?e?r?h?|a?h?s?r?e?|a?h?s?e?r?|a?h?r?s?e?|a?h?r?e?s?|a?h?e?s?r?|a?h?e?r?s?|a?r?s?h?e?|a?r?s?e?h?|a?r?h?s?e?|a?r?h?e?s?|a?r?e?s?h?|a?r?e?h?s?|a?e?s?h?r?|a?e?s?r?h?|a?e?h?s?r?|a?e?h?r?s?|a?e?r?s?h?|a?e?r?h?s?|r?s?h?a?e?|r?s?h?e?a?|r?s?a?h?e?|r?s?a?e?h?|r?s?e?h?a?|r?s?e?a?h?|r?h?s?a?e?|r?h?s?e?a?|r?h?a?s?e?|r?h?a?e?s?|r?h?e?s?a?|r?h?e?a?s?|r?a?s?h?e?|r?a?s?e?h?|r?a?h?s?e?|r?a?h?e?s?|r?a?e?s?h?|r?a?e?h?s?|r?e?s?h?a?|r?e?s?a?h?|r?e?h?s?a?|r?e?h?a?s?|r?e?a?s?h?|r?e?a?h?s?|e?s?h?a?r?|e?s?h?r?a?|e?s?a?h?r?|e?s?a?r?h?|e?s?r?h?a?|e?s?r?a?h?|e?h?s?a?r?|e?h?s?r?a?|e?h?a?s?r?|e?h?a?r?s?|e?h?r?s?a?|e?h?r?a?s?|e?a?s?h?r?|e?a?s?r?h?|e?a?h?s?r?|e?a?h?r?s?|e?a?r?s?h?|e?a?r?h?s?|e?r?s?h?a?|e?r?s?a?h?|e?r?h?s?a?|e?r?h?a?s?|e?r?a?s?h?|e?r?a?h?s?)$
```

Obviously this can be simplified + optimised quite a bit, but is still not a great idea.

**EDIT:** Functions for shorter output:

```
public  static String permutation(String str) {
    return "^(" + permutation("",str) + ")$";
 }

 private static String permutation(String prefix, String str) {
   String s = "";
   int n = str.length();
   if (n == 0) return prefix;
   else {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       if (i != n-1)
         s += prefix + str.charAt(i) + "?(" +
            permutation("", str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n))+")|";
       else
         s += prefix + str.charAt(i) + "?" +
            permutation("", str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
   }
   return s;
}
```

Prints:

```
^(s?(h?(a?(r?(e?)|e?r?)|r?(a?(e?)|e?a?)|e?a?(r?)|r?a?)|a?(h?(r?(e?)|e?r?)|r?(h?(e?)|e?h?)|e?h?(r?)|r?h?)|r?(h?(a?(e?)|e?a?)|a?(h?(e?)|e?h?)|e?h?(a?)|a?h?)|e?h?(a?(r?)|r?a?)|a?(h?(r?)|r?h?)|r?h?(a?)|a?h?)|h?(s?(a?(r?(e?)|e?r?)|r?(a?(e?)|e?a?)|e?a?(r?)|r?a?)|a?(s?(r?(e?)|e?r?)|r?(s?(e?)|e?s?)|e?s?(r?)|r?s?)|r?(s?(a?(e?)|e?a?)|a?(s?(e?)|e?s?)|e?s?(a?)|a?s?)|e?s?(a?(r?)|r?a?)|a?(s?(r?)|r?s?)|r?s?(a?)|a?s?)|a?(s?(h?(r?(e?)|e?r?)|r?(h?(e?)|e?h?)|e?h?(r?)|r?h?)|h?(s?(r?(e?)|e?r?)|r?(s?(e?)|e?s?)|e?s?(r?)|r?s?)|r?(s?(h?(e?)|e?h?)|h?(s?(e?)|e?s?)|e?s?(h?)|h?s?)|e?s?(h?(r?)|r?h?)|h?(s?(r?)|r?s?)|r?s?(h?)|h?s?)|r?(s?(h?(a?(e?)|e?a?)|a?(h?(e?)|e?h?)|e?h?(a?)|a?h?)|h?(s?(a?(e?)|e?a?)|a?(s?(e?)|e?s?)|e?s?(a?)|a?s?)|a?(s?(h?(e?)|e?h?)|h?(s?(e?)|e?s?)|e?s?(h?)|h?s?)|e?s?(h?(a?)|a?h?)|h?(s?(a?)|a?s?)|a?s?(h?)|h?s?)|e?s?(h?(a?(r?)|r?a?)|a?(h?(r?)|r?h?)|r?h?(a?)|a?h?)|h?(s?(a?(r?)|r?a?)|a?(s?(r?)|r?s?)|r?s?(a?)|a?s?)|a?(s?(h?(r?)|r?h?)|h?(s?(r?)|r?s?)|r?s?(h?)|h?s?)|r?s?(h?(a?)|a?h?)|h?(s?(a?)|a?s?)|a?s?(h?)|h?s?)$
```

Comment: To fail much quicker, it would be better at the start of the regex to first insist that the word only contains the right letters and that it isn't greater in length `^(?=[share]{1,5}$)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach :

1. Iterate through your string array to create a `MultiMap<String, String>` (if you're using the Guava library or `HashMap<String, List<String>>` if you're using the java.util) where the key is the sorted word and the values are legal words for that sorted string. This would be your preprocessing step, so you'll only have to do this once. Subsequent searches will be relatively fast since your hashmap already exists (compared to looping through your dictionary each time to match with some regex, which would be much slower than using a hashmap).
2. Sort your search string, and find all substrings of that sorted string.
3. Iterate through the sorted subset, and search the HashMap or MultiMap to get the values for that sortedsubset string. Keep track
   of all the values, and you have your answer.

I think the problem here is that regex is unsuitable for what you're describing, because you'll still have to loop through your whole dictionary for each search (which you've stored as an array). Whereas, if you create the hashmap (this step is relatively expensive), you'll only be looping through your sorted subset list (this is cheap).

Answer (score 0):

If there are no letters which appear twice in the word, as there are not in `share`, you could use

```
^(?!([share]).*\\1)[share]+$
```

This will match any word made up of some or all the letters in `share`.

The negative look-ahead `(?!)` containing a back reference `\\1` to what was matched in the brackets, prevents a match if a letter appears more than once.

You can extend this principle to handle words with letters that appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is an example of how you could do this.  However you should read these articles about catastrophic back tracking:

[Runaway Regular Expressions: Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

[Regex Performance](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html)

```
^(?!.*s.*s)(?!.*h.*h)(?!.*a.*a)(?!.*r.*r)(?!.*e.*e)(?![^share]).*$
```

If you Wanted to allow 2 Letters "s" like shares to allow the word sashes you could do it like.

```
^(?!.*s.*s.*s)(?!.*h.*h)(?!.*a.*a)(?!.*r.*r)(?!.*e.*e)(?![^share]).*$
```

the idea being less than 3 "s" in the word is OK...

Comment: It is quite easy to avoid catastrophic backtracking, by using possessive quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

An approach that doesn't use pattern matching, but gets to the root of the problem, is to create an array with the count of each character in the target word: "deaf" would be the array (1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,...).

Then as you loop over your dictionary, you prepare the same array for each word and subtract it from the target word's array - if there are any negative values in the array of differences, the word can't be made up from the letters of the target word.